# Error during JavaFxPorts ioslaunch with the following gradle file

Tags: xcode, javafx, javafxports

I have a javafx project and I am trying to port it to IOS using javafxports. I get an error saying

```
[SUB] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
[SUB]   "_[j]projectName[infostruct]", referenced from
[SUB]       l_g2 in linker0.o
[SUB] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
[SUB] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The gradle file handling the javafxports looks like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.29'

}
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
    url 'https://jitpack.io'
}
mainClassName = project.ext.get('mainClass')
jfxmobile {
downConfig {
    version = '3.8.0'
    // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
    plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
}
android {
    targetSdkVersion = 21
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
ios {
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    forceLinkClasses = [
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',
            'javax.annotations.**.*',
            'javax.inject.**.*',
            'javax.json.**.*',
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
    ]
}
```

Any idea what might be the problem

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file, with the jfxmobile plugin version, if you are using an external library or a native framework? Are you using the iOS simulator?

Answer (score 1):

The following code is needed when you are compiling with XDStrings

```
compileJava {
options.compilerArgs += ["-XDstringConcat=inline"] //important for IOS. See http://docs.gluonhq.com/gluonvm/ at the very bottom
}
```